# Navigation bar is not seen while using present to view another view controller

Tags: swift, swift4.2

I am not able to see the navigation bar in a view controller while presenting it from another view controller

I have tried keeping

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isHidden = false
```

and also tried keeping a navigation controller to the view controller(embedded in).

Controller A:-

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

let viewController =     
storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier:"Identifier")  as! B        

present(viewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

controller B:-

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {           
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isHidden = false

}
```

Comment: Definitely, you will not see If you are PRESENTING View Controller.

Comment: You are ding it StoryBoard OR by Coding? So that i can give you guideline

Comment: You will not see the navigation bar on controller B because you are presenting the controller. If you want to display the navigation bar on Controller B. You have to add the controller B in navigation controller then you have to present the navigation controller not the controller B.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

let ViewController =
storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier:"Identifier") as! B

let vc = UINavigationController(rootViewController: ViewController)

present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing it programmatically then it will help you:-

**SWIFT 4**

```
let vc = UIStoryboard.init(name: "Main", bundle: Bundle.main).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "IKDetailVC") as? IKDetailVC
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc!, animated: true)
```

Answer (score 0):

In the first view controller viewWillAppear(), add this:

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
self.navigationController?.navigationBarHidden = true
}
```

In the second one, add this:

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {

  self.navigationController?.navigationBarHidden = false

}

override func viewDidDisappear(animated: Bool) {

   self.navigationController?.navigationBarHidden = true
}
```

Happy Coding

Comment: navigationBarHidden has been renamed to isNavigationBarHidden